# Bash Comparing Time Stamps

Tags: bash

I have bash script, where I'm looking at the git log of a file, and basically if the timestamp in the file is greater than the minus time i've specified, then alert me via slack, this sort of works, but not on a file which has a much older time stamp, code below;

```
#!/bin/bash
#Variables
NOW=$(date +"%a %b%Oe %H:%M:%S %Y")
MINUS=$(date +"%a %b%Oe %H:%M:%S %Y" --date '-10 min')
VALUEFILES=("helm/components/admin-ui/values" "helm/components/cssr/values")
#should run every 20minutes to catch any changes - also, once a change has been detected, get the author of the change to also send to slack notification
#git clone
#git clone xxx
cd xxx
#testing
echo "Time now with time -10mins"
echo "$NOW"
echo "$MINUS"
echo `pwd`
##########################
#functions
check_time_stamp_values () {
for f in "${VALUEFILES[@]}"; do
  git log -- "$f".yaml > "$f".txt
  grep "Date" "$f".txt | awk 'NR==1{ print $2, $3, $4, $5, $6 }' > "$f"-time.txt
  echo "===================================================="
  read -r firstline<"$f"-time.txt
  if [ "$firstline" \> "$MINUS" ]
   then
    cat "$f"-time.txt
    echo "$f.yaml has changed within the last 10minutes - sending slack notification"
    echo "===================================================="
  else
    echo "===================================================="
    cat "$f"-time.txt
    echo "$f.yaml has not changed in the last 10minutes - no action required"
    echo "===================================================="
  fi
done
}
##########################
```

For the above, i get the below output;

```
Tue Nov 1 17:34:10 2022
Tue Nov 1 17:24:10 2022
====================================================
====================================================
Tue Nov 1 17:23:48 2022
values.yaml has not changed in the last 10minutes - no action required
====================================================
====================================================
Wed Oct 26 11:27:15 2022
helm/components/cssr/values.yaml has changed within the last 10minutes
====================================================
```

Anyone have any suggestions ? Many thanks

Comment: Consider doing all your date-stamping using the unix timestamp, which is always seconds. that way you don't have to parse date formats. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/102

Answer (score 0):

Solved this issue by doing the following;

```
NOW=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
MINUS=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" --date '-10 min')
```

Change how the date is displayed, and also changed how the git log is displayed;

```
git log --date=format:'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' "$f".yaml > "$f".txt
```

Now works fine without any issues.